Trying to connect Tradingview Advanced Charts to Birdeye API
I am able to pull data from Birdeye onto my website. I have a whole dropdown menu where it shows every token. I cannot connect it to Tradingview though, it is only showing AAPL ticker.
Has anyone done this before? Can you please help
